# how to fix Base64 mutated encoding?

Tags: encoding, base64, ascii, decoding

I've got a string, that looks like a Base64 ASCII encoded string:
`#2aHR0cDovL2RhdGEwMi1jZG4uZGF0YWxvY2sucnUvZmkybG0vZTAxNGNmZTZhMzE1ZjgyODgyZWUxMmJjOTY5MzQ1MDkvN2ZfVGVzdC5uYS5iZXJlbWVubm9zdC5zMDMuZTAyLldFQi1ETFJpcC4yNUt1em1pY2g\/\/b2xvbG8=uYTEuMTYuMTEuMjIubXA0`

If I decode it without any edit, it seems like a mess, but if I remove 2 chars from the very begining (`#2`), it decodes into a mostly correct string:

`http://data02-cdn.datalock.ru/fi2lm/e014cfe6a315f82882ee12bc96934509/7f_Test.na.beremennost.s03.e02.WEB-DLRip.25Kuzmich?`

but is still not complete. This URL should be like:

`http://data02-cdn.datalock.ru/fi2lm/f03143c36c778262bd9906da5d545f85/7f_Test.na.beremennost.s03.e02.WEB-DLRip.25Kuzmich.a1.16.11.22.mp4`

If I remove some more characters from initial string (`#2aHR0cDovL2RhdGEwMi1jZG4uZ`), I get a corrupted text with correct ending of decoded URL:

```
][KLKLMMLMYYLLML
LK\K\[Y[LPQ\R^ZXololo.a1.16.11.22.mp4
```

Is it a regular problem of base64 encoding or maybe there is some sort of mutation in encoded string and it can be solved?

In my experiments i used [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/)

Comment: Besides the backslashes, after the URL part, with the start of the query string after `?` non-ASCII characters follow. It looks more like an error on the sending side, wrong encoding of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes should not be backslashed and there should not be an equals sign in the middle of the stream.

If I remove the backslashed slashes and the equals sign, I get

`http://data02-cdn.datalock.ru/fi2lm/e014cfe6a315f82882ee12bc96934509/7f_Test.na.beremennost.s03.e02.WEB-DLRip.25Kuzmich.16.11.22.184`

I don't think there's anything "regular" about this corruption. Lucky they didn't inject valid base64 or a lot of spurious junk.